# Unable to sign in to Heroku with SalesForce

Tags: authentication, heroku, salesforce

I am unable to sign in Heroku via the SalesForce Authenticator app. The does not work anymmore and I cannot contact Heroku support because an automated email replies that my email adress is not known (even tho I have many emails/notifications from Heroku to this email adres).

I am getting very frustrated not being able to login via SalesForce and not being able to get support from Heroku.

Does anyone have suggestions what to do next?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because [we literally cannot help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577). Contact Heroku support.